# how to change web.config when upgrading to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient 4.3

Tags: azure-storage

I'd like to know how to change web.config when upgrading to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient 4.3. Current web.config is like

```
<assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.7.0.0" newVersion="1.7.0.0" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly delete it. This configuration is used for binding "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient" reference which is older than 1.7.0.0 to the assembly whose version is 1.7.0.0. For example, originally the project references Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient 1.5.0.0 in compile time, after this part is added to web.config, it can leverage Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient 1.7.0.0 instead of 1.5.0.0 in run time, as long as the assembly is backward-compatible.

Because you have replaced "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll" with "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll" (both name and version are different), this configuration is not needed at all.